# Maven 3.0.5 hangs on interactive archetype:generate

Tags: java, linux, maven

When I run

```
mvn archetype:generate
```

The archetypes are listed as expected and I get asked which archetype to use and which version of the archetype, but then after (seemingly) downloading Maven just hangs forever until I interrupt with Ctrl+C.

```
1627: remote -> us.fatehi:schemacrawler-archetype-plugin-dbconnector (-)
1628: remote -> us.fatehi:schemacrawler-archetype-plugin-lint (-)
1629: local -> org.glassfish.javaeetutorial.firstcup:dukes-age-archetype (dukes-age-archetype)
1630: local -> org.glassfish.javaeetutorial.firstcup:firstcup-war-archetype (The web front-end for the First Cup Tutorial example.)
1578
Choose a number or apply filter (format: [groupId:]artifactId, case sensitive contains): 810: Choose org.wildfly.swarm:archetype version: 
1: 1.0.0.Alpha6
2: 1.0.0.Alpha7
3: 1.0.0.Alpha8
3
Choose a number: 3: Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/wildfly/swarm/archetype/1.0.0.Alpha8/archetype-1.0.0.Alpha8.jar
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/wildfly/swarm/archetype/1.0.0.Alpha8/archetype-1.0.0.Alpha8.jar (3 KB at 16.6 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/wildfly/swarm/archetype/1.0.0.Alpha8/archetype-1.0.0.Alpha8.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/wildfly/swarm/archetype/1.0.0.Alpha8/archetype-1.0.0.Alpha8.pom (2 KB at 37.2 KB/sec)
```

I have the same problem on two computers on different networks which to me says that it's not really a problem with my network but rather a configuration-problem or some esoteric issue with Maven.

My systems look like this:

```
System #1:
Apache Maven 3.0.5
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_91, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.2.0-27-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

System #2:
Apache Maven 3.0.5
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_91, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.13.0-91-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Interestingly running this works

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=org.meh -DartifactId=test -Dpackage=org.meh.test -DarchetypeGroupId=org.wildfly.swarm -DarchetypeArtifactId=archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.0.Alpha8 -DinteractiveMode=false
```

But I need interactive mode to work on my systems and I don't really know how to continue with troubleshooting this.

Btw, doing regular builds with Maven for my existing projects works fine.

Comment: It does not hang it waits for your input...

Comment: @khmarbaise It turns out you're sort of right :-)
It's waiting for _all_ the upcoming input without prompting me for it. So if I enter someGroupId [enter], someArtifactId [enter], someVersion [enter], somePackage [enter] and Y [enter] it generates the project. So it still works, it's just completely unusable to anyone who doesn't know the order of everything that it is supposed to prompt the user for.
I'd still like to know why this is though since to me this means it is broken.

Comment: You have defined in one of your outputs `-DinteractiveMode=false` which prevents manuall inputs. And what exactly do you mean is broken? If you have further details please file in a ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARCHETYPE

Comment: @khmarbaise With -DinteractiveMode=false it works, all the input is done via the command-line. Omitting this, i.e. using interactive mode, I am being prompted for input _after_ I've made the input. So I have to know in which order to put in the different pieces of input because I'm not being prompted with anything explaining what to write. It's telling me what to input after I've already done the input. I would call that being broken.